# POST array data with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, http, post

I'm trying to post some data to a http connector but cant figure out how i can post Array data...

My data Looks like that:

```
var data = [{ 
    key:'myKey',
    keyName:'myKeyName',
    value:'value',
    valueName:'valueName' 
}, { 
    key:'mySecondKey', 
    keyName:'mySecondKeyName',
    value:'secondValue',
    valueName:'secondValueName'
}, ...and so on ];
```

I try to post it via Ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:   "POST",
    url:    url,
    data:   data,
    error:  function(){
        alert("Error");
    },
    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

The request Returns ok but when i look at the request data it Posts `undefined=value&undefined=secondValue`

How can i solve this? I Need to save all those informations for configurations

A simple post with just some keys and values like `key=value&key2=value2` works like a charm.

Comment: What format does the server expect the data to be in?

Comment: You should serialize your json object before send it, like: `data: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: @Alessandro — Only if the server expects the data to be in JSON format … and only if you set the content-type header to match.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming you're making a POST request with a JSON payload. First, you want to make sure your payload is formatted JSON correctly, use: http://pro.jsonlint.com/

Secondly, you can send the payload using JSON.stringify and you will want to set the contentType:

**data: JSON.stringify(data),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"**

If you run this and look at your network tab in Dev Tools in Chrome, it will error out, but you will at least see the payload formatted to send to the server:
http://prntscr.com/f8hf6s

```js
var data = [{
    "key": "myKey",
    "keyName": "myKeyName",
    "value": "value",
    "valueName": "valueName"
  },
  {
    "key": "mySecondKey",
    "keyName": "mySecondKeyName",
    "value": "secondValue",
    "valueName": "secondValueName"
  }
];

var url = "http://swapi.co/api/";

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  error: function() {
    alert("Error");
  },
  success: function() {
    alert("OK");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe, but it is a JS object array in his example, so I went with a default guess...